# Serialize class object giving wrong xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

In silverlight i have xml like:

```
<A>
    < A1>
       <B>
        < B1>a1.1</B1>
        <B1>a1.2</B1>
        </B>
    < /A1>

    < A1>
          <B>
          <B1>a1.3< /B1>
          <B1>a1.4</B1>
          </B>
    </A1>
</A>
```

My class are like this
A.cs

```
namespace Check
{
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "A")]
  public class A
  {

    [XmlElement("A1")]
       public List<A1> A1 { get; set; } 

  }
}
```

and A1.cs is:

```
namespace Check
{
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "A1")]
  public class A1
  {  
        [XmlArray("B")]
        [XmlArrayItem("B1", typeof(string))]
        public List<string> B { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Class B.cs is

```
namespace Check
{
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "B")]
  public class B
  {

        [XmlArray("B")]
        [XmlArrayItem("B1", typeof(string))]
        public List<string> B1 { get; set; }

  }
}
```

And i try to serialize ike this, In Xml.cs:

```
namespace Check
{
    public static class Xml
    {
        public static string ToXml(this object objectToSerialize)
        {
             var memory = new MemoryStream();
             var serial = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
             serial.Serialize(memory, objectToSerialize);  
            var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            return utf8.GetString(memory.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memory.Length);  
        }
    }
}
```

Ans Main Function class is :

```
namespace Check
{
    public  class ControlClass
    {
        public  void Main()
        {
            var a = new A() ;
            var xml = a.ToXml();

         }
    }
}
```

Is my approach to serialize correct ? If not please correct me ?

My output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Comment: Well... does it work?

Comment: @MarcGravell Its output is i  have updated "Also i made a change in cLASS a"

Comment: @MarcGravell Iam trying since morning but i dont know why it dont show the full xml (Only headings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct... ish. The reason it isn't showing more is because your `A` instance only has a single property (`A1`), and that has a `null` value. Add the data and it appears:

```
var a = new A {
    A1 = new List<A1> {
        new A1 { B = new List<string> { "a1.1", "a1.2" } },
        new A1 { B = new List<string> { "a1.3", "a1.4" } }
    }
};
```

Even an empty list would have helped. For that reason, you might prefer to use:

```
[XmlElement("A1")]
public List<A1> A1 { get { return a1; } }
private readonly List<A1> a1 = new List<Check.A1>();
```

and:

```
[XmlArray("B")]
[XmlArrayItem("B1", typeof(string))]
public List<string> B { get { return b1; } }
private readonly List<string> b1 = new List<string>();
```

along with:

```
var a = new A {
    A1 = {
        new A1 { B = { "a1.1", "a1.2" } },
        new A1 { B = { "a1.3", "a1.4" } }
    }
};
```

Note: to remove the default namespace alias declarations:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
serial.Serialize(memory, objectToSerialize, ns);
```

This then has output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
  <A1>
    <B>
      <B1>a1.1</B1>
      <B1>a1.2</B1>
    </B>
  </A1>
  <A1>
    <B>
      <B1>a1.3</B1>
      <B1>a1.4</B1>
    </B>
  </A1>
</A>
```

Comment: i have one question in your answer How will you do if i insert <A>  <A1>...B's Stuff first A1....</A1> <C>Check1</C> <A1>... again B's stuff for second A1....</A1> . How will manage the object intialisation if we have to display them in xml in same order. I mean first A1 then C then A1(the last one).

Comment: @user234839 `XmlSerializer` does not support that scenario. If you need interleaved xml, then you would be better using `XElement` to construct it.

Comment: could you please see here once . I have asked with lore detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783884/c-sharp-serialising-xml-error-while-intializing-values-to-class-object

Comment: @user234839 my answer will be the same there as here: `XmlSerializer` does not support that; to construct xml in that format, use `XElement` or `XmlDocument`

Comment: What changes i need to do in my classes I mean with what i will replace "XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType())" and "XmlRoot" and "XmlElement" and "XmlArray" and "XmlArrayItem" in my code ? (I mean it's equivalent)

Comment: Basically, it is a DOM model; please look at the `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` examples on MSDN. You would be writing code to construct the DOM in the entirety

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54126/discussion-between-user234839-and-marc-gravell).